# ant + Junit giving null pinter exception

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am using junit4.10.jar and getting these errors, though test cases are executed completely fine.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.fireTaskFinished(Project.java:2200)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
>   cutor.java:41)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Have no idea from where I can debug these. Please help.

Here is my ant call

```
    <target name="test" depends="compile" >
        <junit >
            <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
            <test name="com.test.TestCase" />
        </junit>
    </target>
    <path id="test.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${classes}" />
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I was reading the output from console and has set

System.setOut(null);

for this reason System.out.println() in ant source code was throwing null pointer.